# Two Controllers and 1 View in Laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I have one issue to solve about some calculations in Laravel 5.1, and until now the best solution that I found is to create Two different controllers, one to handle calculation for a specific item:

```
Route::get('company/convert/{note}','ScenarioController@NoteConvert');
```

And one for all items:

```
Route::get('company/convert','ScenarioController@AllNotesConvert');
```

Both will use render the same view.

**My question is: Is a good practice to do this ?**

In my head one good solution is to use just one route and receive 1 specific note or all of them in some variable through the request.
Something like:

> $http.get('/company/convert/',data)

Where `data` will receive 1 or all notes that will be converted.

P.S.: I'm using AngularJS to call this routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer having one method in your controller you have to change your route a bit:

```
Route::get('company/convert/{note?}','ScenarioController@NoteConvert');
```

And your method would be something like

```
public function NoteConvert($note=null)
{
    if ($note == null) {
       // do all convertions
       return view()
    }
    // single convertion
   ...
}
```

This way *NoteConvert* method will be the one that will handle multiple and single convertions.

Don't forget to remove

```
Route::get('company/convert','ScenarioController@AllNotesConvert');
```

It won't be necessary anymore

Edit:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#parameters-optional-parameters

Comment: The ? represents an optional parameter, is that right? If so I think this is a neat solution

Comment: Yes, if you give a look to docs you can see different routing options, such as ? for optional paramenter

Comment: I used this approach and worked for me. Thanks for the help guys o//

Answer (score 1):

the best way for me, will be to passe an optional parameter in the url and check it on the controller.

Answer (score 0):

i think your task is  to produce the data of all items and specific data with filter using note argument  in the view.

i reccomend you to create the route like this

```
Route::controller('company', 'ScenarioController');
```

then  create a controller with two function like this

```
  public function getIndex()
          {
             return view('convert');

      }
```

here convert is name view blade .

```
 public function postFilter($note)
      {
       $x= // do what you want
       return view('convert', compact('x'));      
      }
```

then add a filter in the blade using a  checkbox and make the form action url as 
"company/filter/{note}".

this is the better practice i think.

refer implicit routing here. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers